# Retrieve href starting with in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract `href` starting with `magnet`:

`item['magnet']=response.xpath('//[@id="content"]/article/div[starts-with(@href,"magnet:")]/@href').extract()`

I get empty results.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're missing a `)` for your `contains`. Btw, xpath also has `starts-with`.

Comment: Yes, thanks i corrected the question. In every page there is at least one href starting with magnet, probably the path isn't correct, the magnet are in the class entry-content, but i still can't retrieve the href(empy result, no errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to extract specific link with `magnet` I propose to
1.Extract all `<a>` tags.

2.Filter all links that don't contain `magnet:` in `href` attribute:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ....
    item["magnet"] = [link for link in response.css("a::attr(href)").extract() if "magnet:" in link]
```

Comment: It works greatly, thanks. I just had to put it in a list and then take the first  -> [0]